# Get the Selection Type in WPF RichTextBox Bullet List in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox

After discovering there is a way to change a WPF RichTextBox Bullet List ListMarker style in VB.NET, I've run into a problem involving partial selections.

The following code can change the bullet types on a WPF Rich Text Box:

```
    Private Sub BulletList(intType As Integer)

        With rtfActiveEdit
            ' Tries to avoid crashing...
            Try

                ' Only operates if there's something selected...
                If Not IsNothing(.Selection.Start.Paragraph) And Not IsNothing(.Selection.End.Paragraph) Then
                    ' Sets up data processing variables...
                    Dim phStart As Block = .Selection.Start.Paragraph
                    Dim phEnd As Block = .Selection.End.Paragraph
                    Dim strSelect As String = .Selection.Text
                    Dim strList() As String
                    Dim lstOutput As List
                    Dim itmAdd As ListItem
                    Dim strPickup As String = ""
                    Dim phHold As Paragraph
                    Dim intItem As Integer = 0
                    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
                    Dim strBreak As String = vbCrLf
                    Dim strTab As String = vbTab
                    Dim blnList As Boolean = False
                    Dim blnPlain As Boolean = False
                    ' Obtains the highlighted material...
                    strList = Split(strSelect, strBreak)
                    ' Counts up items in the highlighted material...
                    intCount = strList.Length
                    ' Sets up the bullet point style...
                    Dim nowStyle As TextMarkerStyle
                    Dim tmStyle As TextMarkerStyle
                    ' Responds based on user input...
                    Select Case intType
                        Case 0  ' NONE
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.None
                        Case 1  ' DISC (Default)
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.Disc
                        Case 2  ' BOX
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.Box
                        Case 3  ' CIRCLE
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.Circle
                        Case 4  ' SQUARE
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.Square
                        Case 5  ' DECIMAL NUMBERS
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.Decimal
                        Case 6  ' LOWERCASE
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.LowerLatin
                        Case 7  ' UPPERCASE
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.UpperLatin
                        Case 8  ' LOWERCASE ROMAN
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.LowerRoman
                        Case 9  ' UPPERCASE ROMAN
                            tmStyle = TextMarkerStyle.UpperRoman
                    End Select
                    ' Reacts based on whether selected contents include a list...
                    If phStart.Parent.GetType() Is GetType(ListItem) And phEnd.Parent.GetType() Is GetType(ListItem) Then
                        ' Loads the current list type...
                        nowStyle = CType(phStart.Parent, ListItem).List.MarkerStyle
                        ' Responds based on the list type...
                        Select Case nowStyle.ToString
                            Case "Disc", "Box", "Circle", "Square"
                                ' Removes BULLET LIST formatting
                                EditingCommands.ToggleBullets.Execute(vbNull, rtfActiveEdit)
                            Case "Decimal", "LowerLatin", "UpperLatin", "LowerRoman", "UpperRoman"
                                ' Removes ORDERED LIST formatting...
                                EditingCommands.ToggleNumbering.Execute(vbNull, rtfActiveEdit)
                            Case Else
                                ' Should NEVER happen...

                        End Select
                        ' Triggers list reprocessing...
                        blnList = True
                        ' Only triggers complete list removal if the user chooses...
                        If intType = 0 Then
                            ' Triggers list removal...
                            blnPlain = True
                        End If
                    Else
                        ' Only triggers complete list blockage if the user chooses "None" on a NON-LIST...
                        If intType = 0 Then
                            ' Prevents reformatting "NONE" as a list (YIKES!!!)...
                            blnPlain = True
                            Beep()
                        End If
                    End If

                    ' Only operates if the list needs formatting...
                    If blnPlain = False Then
                        ' Prepares to add items to the new list...
                        lstOutput = New List
                        ' Sets the style for the list...
                        lstOutput.MarkerStyle = tmStyle
                        ' Loops through the selected text...
                        For intItem = 0 To intCount - 1
                            ' Collects the item from the array...
                            strPickup = strList(intItem)
                            ' Removes unwanted list markers that survived formatting removal...
                            If blnList = True Then
                                ' Strips unwanted formatting...
                                strPickup = Right(strList(intItem), Len(strList(intItem)) - InStr(strList(intItem), strTab))
                                ' Only strips off leading tab characters...
                                While Strings.Left(strPickup, 1) = strTab
                                    ' Removes the tab...
                                    strPickup = Right(strPickup, Len(strPickup) - 1)
                                End While
                            End If
                            ' Creates a new paragraph...
                            phHold = New Paragraph
                            ' Adds text to the paragraph...
                            phHold.Inlines.Add(strPickup)
                            ' Adds the paragraph to a new list item...
                            itmAdd = New ListItem(phHold)
                            ' Adds the new list item to the new list...
                            lstOutput.ListItems.Add(itmAdd)
                        Next

                        ' Attempts to resolve how to handle the selection...
                        Dim objPlace As Type
                        ' Attempts to get the element just before this one...
                        objPlace = .Selection.GetType
                        ' Operates based on whether the item just before the selection is a list item...
                        If objPlace Is GetType(List) Then


                            MsgBox("This is the part that needs to be changed...")

                            ' needs to select the affected list item

                            ' list item needs to get a new paragraph
                            ' new paragraph needs to get a new list
                            ' new list needs to be the output


                        Else

                            MsgBox("This part only works on fully selected lists")

                            ' Clears the selection (YIKES!!!)...
                            .Selection.Text = ""
                            ' Attempts to clear a leading carriage return from the list (YIKES!!!)...
                            .Document.Blocks.Remove(.CaretPosition.Paragraph)
                            ' This step constistently fails when part of a list is selected...
                            ' REWRITE IT TO FIX THE PROBLEM
                            ' Inserts the list directly into the document...
                            .Document.Blocks.InsertBefore(.CaretPosition.Paragraph, lstOutput)

                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Notifies the user...
                MsgBox("Try selecting something simpler." & vbCrLf & ex.Message, vbExclamation, "Formatting Failed")
            End Try

        End With


    End Sub
```

This code is activated by a menu with the different bullet point styles assigned a value.  When the user selects a style from the menu, the buttons send the appropriate value.

I have tried to determine what the selection type is, in an attempt to force the partially selected part of the bullet list or numbered list to be nested according to what's in the link.  But the best I've gotten is "System.Runtime.Type," with the current code.  An earlier configuration could get the element adjacent to the selection, but the only type that ever gave was "Run."  If the system could identify that the selection has a "ListItem," it would be possible to move on from there.

[Creating Nested Bullet List At Runtime](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05a4399a-8567-48d8-b5f8-8bffac5266da/creating-nested-bullet-list-at-runtime) is possible, and that involved adding to a list after it was included in the document.

If my program could identify the type of element being selected, it could be programmed to branch and handle the partial selection.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that getting the parent requires [iterating through the type of object by moving the text pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392196/how-to-get-the-parent-tag-of-selected-text-in-richtextbox).

```
' Attempts to resolve how to handle the selection...
Dim objPlace As DependencyObject
' Identifies the caret position to begin the loop...
Dim tpPlace As TextPointer = .CaretPosition
' Gets the first object type...
objPlace = .CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Backward)
' Sets up a feedback variable that's easier to read or translate...
Dim strPlace As String = ""
Dim intPlace As Integer = 0
' Attempts to loop through parent objects...
Do While Not (objPlace.GetType Is GetType(List))
    ' Increments the counter...
    intPlace += 1
    ' Moves the text pointer one unit farther over...
    tpPlace = tpPlace.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward)
    ' Gets the object...
    objPlace = tpPlace.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Backward)
    ' Exits the loop if it runs too long, or if nothing is found...
    If intPlace < 1000 And Not IsNothing(objPlace) Then
        ' Gets the object type...
        strPlace = objPlace.GetType.ToString
    Else
        ' Exits the loop...
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

The code above identifies the object type, then creates a text pointer that can be moved by the program to find the desired object type if the current object isn't a match.  It keeps moving the text pointer earlier and earlier, until it locates something it can work with.  A condition limits the code from running endlessly by counting the number of loops that have run.

**EDIT:**  The loop is modified to allow the program to abort if objPlace is nothing.  This prevents crashing if the text pointer reaches the beginning of the document, where adjacent elements would be impossible to find.